# ClassNotFoundException when running Kotlin test class in JUnit in STS

Tags: junit, kotlin

I am just starting with Kotlin and recently followed tutorial on: https://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/v373/SpringToolSuiteAndKotlin.html

In my project however I changed src/main/kotlin and src/test/kotlin to say src/../java instead. I deleted .project, .classpath, .settings and target folders and re-imported project to make sure eclipse has fresh configuration. However I have issues when running JUnit tests on .kt test classes from STS.
Eclipse itself compiles tests class fine.

I receive error from console (org.jetbrains.kotlin.ui.console):

```
E:\Lhasa\Workspace\Ecosystem-Java8-Master-STS-3.8.4\kotlin-demo\src\test\java\lhasa\demo\KotlinSimpleTest.kt
    ERROR: Unresolved reference: KotlinLhasaDemo (5, 19)
    ERROR: Unresolved reference: KotlinLhasaDemo (11, 14)
```

JUnit luncher don't see Kotlin test class at all (as it didn't get compiled).
However if I run mvn install, mvn runs fine that class. Re-launching after STS JUnit will again produce error message, but this time it will discover the class and run tests on it.
Updating the .kt class however will again be not seen by Eclipse compilator.
I guess JUnit launcher doesn't compile Kotlin test classes, I don't know how to fix it.

This is my test class:

```
package com.example.demo

import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Assert.*;
import lhasa.demo.KotlinLhasaDemo

class KotlinSimpleTest {
    @Test
    fun testCallNormalKotlin()
    {
        val demo = KotlinLhasaDemo();
        demo.normalFunction();
        demo.stringFunction();
        val number = demo.incrementFunction("1");
        assertEquals("2", number);
    }
}
```

This is the class I am calling (it works fine):

```
package lhasa.demo

class KotlinLhasaDemo {

    fun normalFunction() {

    }

    fun stringFunction(): String {
        return  "" // ; not required
    }

    fun incrementFunction(number: String): String {
        var i = Integer.parseInt(number)
        i++
        return Integer.toString(i)
    }
}
```

I am using STS 3.9.5 with Kotlin STS 0.8.6 extension.

Comment: Kotlin is compiled to standard JVM class files, same as Java does. That's the reason you're able to run them, once you get them to compile. The main question is - why did you change the paths in the first place?

Comment: It does not matter. if I create brand new project as in tutorial and modify kotlin test class in STS, it does not get auto compiled to .class file. However it works for main classes, so I think I need to report it as a bug.

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem. Did you find any solution?